# Generating random values form an array

Tags: javascript

I've been learning JavaScript for only one week so please be gentle! Tried searching for an answer but no luck.

I am writing a names generator and I want the user to click on a button "girlButton" to see a random girl name, same with boys. The problem is that it is generating one name for each button and to see another name, I need to refresh the page. I want to be able to smash the buttons and see a different name every time. I am pretty sure it's something basic, but I am stuck so please could you help? :) I am not pasting Arrays because they are pretty long. Thanks!

```js
const girlsNamesArray = girlsNames.split(' ');
console.log(girlsNamesArray);

const boysNamesArray = boysNames.split(' ');
console.log(boysNamesArray);

let randomGirl = girlsNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * girlsNamesArray.length)];
const girlButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--girl');

let randomBoy = boysNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * boysNamesArray.length)];
const boyButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--boy');

let proposedName = document.querySelector('.names__idea');

girlButton.addEventListener('click', e => proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij córkę ${randomGirl.slice(0, -1)}`);

boyButton.addEventListener('click', e => proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij syna ${randomBoy.slice(0, -1)}`);
```

I want to be able to hit buttons multiple times and see different values from the array.

Comment: You're only creating the random index once, when declaring the `randomGirl` and `randomBoy` variables. You need to do that within your click event handler, before setting the `innerHTML` to the randomized name result.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following code block

```
        const girlsNamesArray = girlsNames.split(' ');
        console.log(girlsNamesArray);
        const boysNamesArray = boysNames.split(' ');
        console.log(boysNamesArray);

        const girlButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--girl');
        const boyButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--boy');

        let proposedName = document.querySelector('.names__idea');

        girlButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const string = girlsNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * girlsNamesArray.length)];
            proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij córkę ${string}`
        });

        boyButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const string = boysNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * boysNamesArray.length)];
            proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij syna ${string}`
        });
```

Here you have to write the logic of random inside the event binding.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to write that function but was so lost! Thanks again and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

When a button is clicked, all it does right now is set the `innerText` of the `proposedName` element. It doesn't run the random number generator again. So you need to group the code to re-run it:

```js
let girlsNames = "gloriax deborahx fayex"
let boysNames = "jackx petex stefanx"

const girlsNamesArray = girlsNames.split(' ');
console.log(girlsNamesArray);

const boysNamesArray = boysNames.split(' ');
console.log(boysNamesArray);

let randomGirl;
const girlButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--girl');

let randomBoy;
const boyButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--boy');

let proposedName = document.querySelector('.names__idea');

function selectNewNames() {
  randomBoy = boysNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * boysNamesArray.length)];
  randomGirl = girlsNamesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * girlsNamesArray.length)];
}

girlButton.addEventListener('click', e => {selectNewNames(); proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij córkę ${randomGirl.slice(0, -1)}`});

boyButton.addEventListener('click', e => {selectNewNames(); proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij syna ${randomBoy.slice(0, -1)}`});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="names__button--girl">New girl</button>
<button type="button" class="names__button--boy">New boy</button>
<h2 class="names__idea"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly all the best for your journey.To achieve this, you can move the logic for generating random names inside the event listeners so that every time the button is clicked, a new random name is generated .The code for the same will be something like this.

```
const girlButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--girl');
const boyButton = document.querySelector('.names__button--boy');
const randomIndex = (arr) = >{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}

girlButton.addEventListener('click', e = >{
  let randomGirl = girlsNamesArray[randomIndex(girlsNamesArray)];
  proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij córkę$ {
    randomGirl.slice(0, -1)
  }`;
});

boyButton.addEventListener('click', e = >{
  let randomBoy = boysNamesArray[randomIndex(boysNamesArray)];
  proposedName.innerText = `Nazwij syna $ {
    randomBoy.slice(0, -1)
  }`;
});
```

`